# Receiving the logging messages of a python process opened via subprocess

Tags: python, logging, process, subprocess, interprocess

I have a python program that is using pygame. I want to create another pygame window for some additional content and have a seperate script for that. I use socket and localhost for communication.

I am using subprocess to run the script that displays the second pygame window. This script has a number of logging messages that are not displayed on the stdout of the terminal I am using. Is there a way to redirect the logging messages so that they are printed to the console alongside the logging messages of the main program?

So far I have set up a logwrapper that captures the logged output:

```
level = logging.DEBUG
def getLogger(module_name):
    wrapper = LogWrapper(module_name)
    return wrapper.getLogger(),wrapper

class LogWrapper():

    def __init__(self,module_name):
        self.module_name = module_name
        self.log_capture_string = None
        self.log_trace = []

    @property
    def trace(self):
        values = self.log_capture_string.getvalue()
        self.log_trace = self.log_trace+values.split("\n")
        return self.log_trace

    def getLogger(self, **kwargs):
        ### Create the logger
        logging.config.dictConfigClass(configuration).configure()
        logger = logging.getLogger(self.module_name)
        logger.setLevel(level)

        ### Setup the console handler with a FIFOIO object
        self.log_capture_string = FIFOIO(32768)
        ch = logging.StreamHandler(self.log_capture_string)
        ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        ### Optionally add a formatter

        ### Add the console handler to the logger
        logger.addHandler(ch)
        logger.info("set up logwrap for {}".format(self.module_name))

        return logger

class FIFOIO(io.TextIOBase):
    def __init__(self, size, *args):
        self.maxsize = size
        io.TextIOBase.__init__(self, *args)
        self.deque = collections.deque()
    def getvalue(self):
        return ''.join(self.deque)
    def write(self, x):
        self.deque.append(x)
        self.shrink()
    def shrink(self):
        if self.maxsize is None:
            return
        size = sum(len(x) for x in self.deque)
        while size > self.maxsize:
            x = self.deque.popleft()
            size -= len(x)
```

But after running the main program and calling subprogram.logwrapper.trace upon termination doesn't capture any of the error messages from the runtime, only the initialization message, so I am looking for a better way to access this information.

Comment: careful with the quadratic complexity of `self.log_trace = self.log_trace+values.split("\n")`, better do `self.log_trace.extend(values.split("\n"))`